# How to get value between tags with sax contenthandler?

Tags: android, xml, sax

I'm parsing some XML with a ContentHandler, and I can get attributes within tags fine, but I don't see how to get the actual values. For example, take this simple xml:

```
<code>
< thing id="12345" key="abcde" >

< description > Some text is here < /description >

< otherdata > I don't actually care about or want this text < /otherdata >

< /thing >
</code>
```

(Apologies for the formatting there...)
So, in my StartElement() I can get the id and key values fine with att.getValue("id") for example. But how do I get the text between the description tags?

Based on reading the docs it look like I need to use the characters() method, but this will presumably occur for all other tags in the xml (the real example is more complex than the above, and I don't need all of it) - how do I relate the character array back to a specific tag? All it gives me is a start and a length but from that I don't know which element it relates to.

I'm obviously missing something obvious here but none of the docs or examples I find seem to help - most examples just show the whole doc being squirted out to a console, which is fine but doesn't help with my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Flag value whenever you parse **description** inside the `startElement()`, and make it false inside the `endElement()`. In between this, you can have value of description inside the `characters()` method.

Answer (score 1):

use 
_data.sectionId = atts.getValue("id");

refer this link for detailed example
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

Comment: Thanks- the atts were working already, but the link you gave me combined with the suggestion from Paresh helped a lot

Comment: If you want any help on XML parsing using different parsers in Android, check this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Answer (score 1):

SAX is a very low-level API for parsing, and the price you pay for this is that you have to manage context and state within your application code. Nearly all SAX applications will maintain a stack of element names, so that when text arrives, you know what element it belongs to by peek()ing at the stack.

SAX seems to be becoming very popular on Android, and I'm not sure whether that's because there's nothing else available or because the efficiency is needed. But the fact is, SAX is a very difficult interface to program to, and for high performance you pay a heavy price in usability.